# Can't connect to wireless networks

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am pretty new to linux and installed it to practice fortran codes we're being taught in school. The install went fine, but I can't connect to Internet via wifi. I tried using a usb adapter as well, but it didn't help connect either. I tried looking for my adapter using lshw and lspci commands and I have two somewhat related devices - a network controller and an ethernet controller, which is realtek semiconductor RTL8111/8168/8411, but I haven't been able to do anything else. Would someone help me out in any way? I have been researching and googling my issue but it hasn't helped yet, new issues keep popping up.

Comment: Please add the output of `lshw`, `lspci` and the OS version to your original post

Comment: What does the command `rfkill list` tell you?

Comment: You haven't given your OS/release details, these provide a huge clue as to the age of your software stack (which can then be compared with your chipset), and if using a LTS release whether or not you're using HWE or GA stack (which you won't likely understand, but providing details of your installed OS will generally tell us this) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide